# Activiti: process don't save any of it variables

Tags: activiti

As I know, Activiti save process variables into ACT_RU_VARIABLE or ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY. My code:

*Process deffinition:*

```
...
<serviceTask id="servicetask1" name="GenerateData" activiti:class="CreateClientService"></serviceTask>
...
```

*ServiceTask:*

```
@Service
public class CreateClientService implements JavaDelegate {

  public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
    MyObj obj = new MyObj():
    execution.setVariable("obj", obj);
  }
}
```

But obj-variable isn't saved!

**My questions:**

1. Why it isn't saved?
2. If I use Activiti + Hibernate, does Activiti save the process variables to ACT_RU_VARIABLE and ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY tables?

Comment: how do you know that it isn't saved?
Btw, you have a `:` instead of `;`
you also missed `@Override` above the method

Comment: Yeah. But process variables are saved when suspend or stop the process or launch the asynch task. I didn't know about that fact.

Comment: that's probably because for the rest of the time (so when process is running and there's no async tasks) activiti stores variable in memory instead of the db. actually the approach make sense.

Comment: Have you checked in `ACT_HI_VARINST` table? Execution tables are cleaned when a process end.